# CSS selector for the div insde first of type element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have HTML like:

```
<tag1>
 <div class="c"> // need to select that
   <tag1>
    <div class="c"> // do not need that
    </div>
   </tag1>
 </div>
</tag1>
```

I want to select the `div` inside the first `tag1` to apply CSS rule

I tried `tag1:first-of-type c {}` but it didn't work.

Comment: `tag1 .c:first-of-type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select **both** classes inside your tag, you simply need a `.` in front of the C:

```css
tag1:first-of-type .c {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<tag1>
 <div class="c">Outer
   <tag1>
    <div class="c">Inner
    </div>
   </tag1>
 </div>
</tag1>
```

Of note, it's actually impossible to **only** style the outer element with your above structure, though you can always get around this by styling the inner element separately with greater **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**:

```css
tag1:first-of-type > .c {
  color: red;
}

tag1:first-of-type tag1 .c {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<tag1>
 <div class="c">Outer
   <tag1>
    <div class="c">Inner
    </div>
   </tag1>
 </div>
</tag1>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I just need to select the `Outer` one no need the `Inner`

Comment: It's impossible to do that with your current structure (assuming that is **exactly** your structure, with no additional IDs or class names). You'll have to style **both** of the segments the way you want the outer segment to be styled, then style the inner segment back to a 'default' state.

Comment: what is the best way to work around that without touching the html structure?

Comment: I showed it in my secondary snippet above -- just style the inner element back to a default state. In my example, all I had to do was change the font colour to black.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* possibly do that in CSS - you will have to *hack* your way through if you can't change your markup.

1. Set the style using `tag1 .c:first-of-type`
2. *Reset* the *inner* `tag1` using `tag1 tag1 .c:first-of-type` selector and `<property>: initial`.

See demo below:

```css
tag1 .c:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}

tag1 tag1 .c:first-of-type {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<tag1>
 <div class="c">1
   <tag1>
    <div class="c">2
    </div>
   </tag1>
 </div>
</tag1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html propably will be surrounded by other tags, for example a body tag. To only target the outer div, simply be more specific.

```
<body>
<tag1>
 <div class="c"> // need to select that
   <tag1>
    <div class="c"> // do not need that
    </div>
   </tag1>
 </div>
</tag1>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body > tag1 > div.c { }
```

Comment: @sreginogemoh: Only possible reason this couldn't work is if your outer tag1 isn't a child of body. Obviously you would need to adapt the selector to work with your actual markup.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward. You just need two rules.

The first rule will select what you need:

```
aside > .c {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
font-weight: bold;
}
```

The second rule will set the normal styles and simultaneously deselect any element which fits the pattern `aside > .c` but which is nested any deeper than the first `aside`:

```
.c, aside aside > .c {
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
font-weight: normal;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
aside {
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
height: 25%;
padding: 12px;
border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

aside > .c {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
font-weight: bold;
}

.c, aside aside > .c {
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<aside>
<div class="c"> // need to select this

<aside>
<div class="c"> // do not need that </div>
</aside>

</div>
</aside>
```